# jQuery $.ajax failing silently, no error messages, and server responded with 200 OK

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I am about to do my head in over this problem. I am using very simple jQuery ajax calls to get values from a database and populate a few select elements with the values, all returned as JSON. It works seamlessly for me on most browsers, however the client is reporting that neither them nor their clients are seeing the result.

I added some Console.log() commands along the way to make sure the code was executing, and it was. Sometimes the ajax GET to the URL in question works, other times is STILL returns 200 OK but the code simply does not execute further, and NO ajax error messages are shown in the error callback.

Here is the code I am using, can someone spot something obvious that may result in some browsers choking? If so, I'd be grateful if you could point it out:

```
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        $j(document).ready(function(){
            //console.log("jQuery has loaded");
            //console.log("attempting to load country list via AJAX call now");
            $j.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.topplaces.co.za/templates/seb_one/positions/search_establishments_filter/search/db.php?q=countries&rand='+Math.random(),
                success: function(data){
                    //console.log("Successfully got country list, going to populate the dropdown now");
                    if(data.length){
                        $j("#country").children("option:not(:first)").remove();
                        $j("#country").attr("disabled", false);
                        $j.each(data, function(resultIndex, result){
                            var o = new Option();
                            $j(o).html(result.country).val(result.country);
                            $j("#country").append(o);
                        })
                        //console.log("Country list should be populated now?");
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    //console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(thrownError);   
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false
            })

            $j("#country").live('change', function(){
                var id = $j(this).val();
                if(id == ""){
                    $j("#province").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $j("#town").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    return false;
                }
                $j.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.topplaces.co.za/templates/seb_one/positions/search_establishments_filter/search/db.php?q=provinces&c='+id+'&rand='+Math.random(),
                    success: function(data){
                    if(data.length){
                        $j("#province").children("option:not(:first)").remove();
                        $j("#province").attr("disabled", false);
                        $j.each(data, function(resultIndex, result){
                            var o = new Option();
                            $j(o).html(result.province).val(result.province);
                            $j("#province").append(o);
                        })
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false
                })
            });

            $j("#province").live('change', function(){
                var id = $j(this).val();
                if(id == ""){
                    $j("#town").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    return false;
                }
                $j.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.topplaces.co.za/templates/seb_one/positions/search_establishments_filter/search/db.php?q=towns&p='+id+'&rand='+Math.random(),
                    success: function(data){
                    if(data.length){
                        $j("#town").children("option:not(:first)").remove();
                        $j("#town").attr("disabled", false);
                        $j.each(data, function(resultIndex, result){
                            var o = new Option();
                            $j(o).html(result.town).val(result.town);
                            $j("#town").append(o);
                        })
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false
                })
            });

        })
```

I have commented out the Consol.log commands for the pure fact that the client was receiving error messages on IE as there is no console.

**EDIT: I failed to mention that this a same domain request and therefore obeys the Same Origin Policy**

The full site is here: http://www.topplaces.co.za/
On the right is a dynamic select group that starts with country and initiates AJAX calls until a Province is selected. The issue, a lot of people say that Country is no loading for them...

Kind regards,
Simon

Comment: Is this cross domain? (answered in edit: no)

What does your return JSON look like? Is it an array? If not, is it an object with a `length` property?

Why is your `error` function commented out in the AJAX options? Without an error handler, failures will be silent.

Comment: @JAAulde - I uncommented it in the above question, this was from my dev copy, but the production site has it commented out. The response is a properly formatted JSON string. As I said, it works for me and about 10 people I asked to test, but then another 10 will say it does not load, and their FireBug console shows the GET request as 200 OK but yet the select is not populated and no errors thrown

Comment: I have added the full site URL: http://www.topplaces.co.za/ to the answer. The set of 3 dynamic selects on the right are what populate from the returned JSON data. At first I had assumed that maybe the client was going via a work place proxy and caching was aggressive, but they wiped (5gb!!!) of cache, no difference, and besides some others on an 'open' web report the select not working too.

Answer (score 5):

Check if your server application always returns valid JSON object, otherwise it will not be accepted because you set `dataType: 'json'`. In this case, `error` function will be executed instead of `success`.

Remove `dataType` parameter and see what happens, try to parse incoming data with `$.parseJSON()` - it will throw an exception if you JSON is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for that reply, it raises some questions. I am returning my JSON with header('Content-Type: text/plain'); is there a MIME type for JSON or is it OK to use text/plain??

Comment: yes, it's OK. just make user your JSON is valid. you may also set your content-type to `application/json` if you prefer :)

Comment: It seems perfectly formed, I used $.parseJSON() in my success function, logged the result to the console, and you can see the perfectly formed JSON objects here: http://skitch.com/simondowdles/8iaw3/topplaces-console-json the code I used was success: `function(data){data = $.parseJSON(data); console.log(data);`...}

Comment: Remember that `dataType` is not for what you want to receive in the response, but what you are sending! **FALSE**

Comment: @DavidDiez That's entirely backwards - the opposite of what you said is true. `dataType` is the type/format you're expecting the response to be. [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Oh thanks! Thats true, I was mistaken with `contenttype`

Comment: @David - Incorrect. From jQuery docs: "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server." - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you may be thinking of contentType...

Comment: @One Stuck Pixel, your select element successfully populates in Chrome/FF, but fails in IE9. hope it helps

Comment: @phantasm - Yes, I think it's the way in which I am traversing the DOM, damn IE to hell... You see, this is bizarre, works for you as well, even in FF< but not for the client, and they are using the latest FF. Could it be that the data is being malformed in some way over the network in which it is passing? But why would everything fail silently then... hmmm

Comment: strangely, now it started to work in IE too... UPD: oh, i see the code changes, so it's OK :)

Comment: The only thing I did was add the new Option() instance directly into the append() statement on the select. Does it work seamlessly in IE for you now? The question now is this: Do I remain with the $.parseJSON() method or can I revert to setting the dataType to json knowing that the returned value is a valus JSON string. Somehow it feels SAFER using parseJSON

Comment: And lastly, I have placed all my calls to populate the select inside of the success handler, should it maybe be inside the complete handler instead?

Comment: setting dataType to json will invoke parseJSON method internally, so it's not a big difference to use one approach or another. as for `complete` handler, i'd suggest to use `success` handler instead, because it doesn't make sense to populate countries if your code failed to receive country list from server

Answer (score 2):

I tried your site but no province is loading. The Json is empty. I tried accesing the php directly and it returns empty as well. Did you check your script?

URL Called
http://www.topplaces.co.za/templates/seb_one/positions/search_establishments_filter/search/db.php?q=provinces&c=Zambia&rand=0.12686952343210578&_=1335360594228

This are the params is see:

```
q:provinces
c:Zambia
rand:0.12686952343210578
_:1335360594228
```

Json Result:
[]

It's really random so I bet it's the php script not returning the json.

Comment: It is very possible that no provinces are loaded for Zambia in the DB as the tables are closely couple with a CCK for Joomla where the clients manage the provinces. I am not stressed about an empty value but more so with the fact that it works for most people here and not the client or their clients... man oh man. Network issues perhaps? Thanks for pointing out the blank value though, it needs to be sorted, appreciate it!

Comment: All I know is that it's not the JS, it's the server since the JSON is empty not only for Zambia but for others and it's totally random. Did you check your logs? See if that php script is generating error? That will help you a lot.

Comment: What others are empty, and is it random to the extent that a country that works will not work the second time? Could it perhaps be that my main code is being called in the success: handler as opposed to the complete: ajax handler? I will try and get my paws on the logs to see if there are any PHP errors. I have direct access to the PHP script responsible for returning the data as I wrote it, is there something I can add in there to further help debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this browser issue with json returned from an ajax call.  The problem was that I had to look at different parts of the returned data in Firefox compared to IE.  For Firefox, `data.text` was `undefined` so I had to use `data.documentElement.firstChild` to find the json:

```
var list = typeof data.text === 'undefined' ? jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery(data.documentElement.firstChild).text()) : jQuery.parseJSON(data.text);
```

Comment: In your case though you must have returned text as a single entry in your JSON object, correct? Mine should just simply be data as I am returning one JSON formatted array. Or am I misunderstanding things a little? I am still learning new things.

Comment: True - In my case the json was wrapped in `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"></string>` tags so my scenario is probably different than yours.

Comment: Aha, yes, you seemed to have returned your data as XML, or at least a string following the same markup conventions, hence documentElement.firstChild was able to step into the first XML like tag of your response. Interesting approach though, and I have made a note of your solution to that problem should I some day face it, thank you.