# jQuery $.ajax failing no error message, server responded with 200 OK

Tags: json, jquery

I have an ajax call that works fine locally, but when I published it into the server, the code is never executed but returns "200 OK" anyway. No "success" code is ejecuted, nor the "error" code. Here's my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/CargadorContadores.aspx/ObtenerContadores",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var myObj = JSON.parse(data.d);

                    for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
                        var element = document.getElementById("LbItem " + myObj[i].MenuItemID);
                        element.innerHTML = "<b>" + element.innerHTML + " (" + myObj[i].Cantidad + ")</b>";
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
            });
        });
```

I also tried to put the complete url in the "url" field but still no luck.
The weird thing is that when I put the complete url directly into the browser, it is still not executing the code. And it works fine locally!!

I know there's a similar post ([jQuery $.ajax failing silently, no error messages, and server responded with 200 OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316111/jquery-ajax-failing-silently-no-error-messages-and-server-responded-with-200)) but is not resolved and it's driving crazy here.

PD: this is NOT cross-domain, my ajax code is in a .ascx and I am trying to call a method on an .aspx

Thanks very much!!!!

**EDIT:** I tried to remove the System.web.extensions reference of my web project and add the dll to my bin, but it's still not working (the 1.0.61025.0 version). Besides, I am running the ASP.NET website in IIS with **framework 2.0**, and I don't have **framework 3.5** installed on my server (but locally I do). Maybe that's the problem? I can't install it because of the client security policies, what shall I do?

**EDIT 2:** I tried doing a simple response from my .aspx, just to test if the problem was in that method, but it is still not executing the success function. Here's my .aspx code:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string ObtenerContadores()
        {

            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("true");
        }
```

and adapted the .ascx

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/CargadorContadores.aspx/ObtenerContadores",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "",
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(dictionary) {
                        alert("hello");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        alert(err.Message);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: The problem is in the server side,  Check the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank everyone for your help.
I finally had to install the 3.5 Framework on the server, I had no choice.
The second I installed it, and updated the web.config dll's references to 3.5, it worked like a charm.

Thanks again!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: "The weird thing is that when I put the complete url directly into the browser, it is still not executing the code."  Your JavaScript is expecting -- requiring -- a JSON response, and is apparently getting no response at all.  This is not a JavaScript problem, but a problem with your .aspx page.

**EDIT:** Based on your comments below, it's clear that the problem is that your .aspx page is not returning what you expect.  Because the .aspx doesn't produce the expected output even when you go to it directly, the problem is in that page, not in the jQuery.

Pretend the .aspx produces `{}`, `false`, or `true`.  Your `success` code will run, but not do anything.  Try putting an `alert("Foo");` in there and watch what happens.  The problem isn't that your jQuery is busted; it's that it isn't getting meaningful input from your .aspx page.

P.S. I would recommend using a variable name other than `data` in your success function, just in case it's getting messed up by the `data` object attribute in your .ajax call.

Comment: I know, that's my problem, that my javascript is not receiveing the response from the .aspx, but locally it works perfectly. There's no error in my code. I'm guessing it's a configuration error, maybe .dlls or something like that.

Comment: What I mean is this. You say that even when you go directly to the URL in question, it's not executing the code.  I interpreted this to mean that you are going to yourserver.whatever/CargadorContadores.aspx/ObtenerContadores and the ASPX isn't executing.  If that's what you're saying the problem is not a jQuery or JSON problem; it's a problem with your .aspx page.  If that's not what you mean, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, but when I do it locally it works fine. Please check my edit on the question

Comment: please read my post where I say "No "success" code is ejecuted, nor the "error" code". The method on the .aspx is not being called at all, regardless of what it's returning.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this more clearly. If your .aspx doesn't execute, even when you go to the page directly, that's why your app isn't working, regardless of what you are trying to do with jQuery.

Comment: I understand, but I already tried to replace the method for a simple "return true" and ONLY do an alert on the success function but it's still not working.

Comment: Are you certain your .ajax call is even firing? If you put `alert("foo");` on the line immediately above the `$.ajax()` call, does it fire?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41427/discussion-between-nicole-and-ed-cottrell)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I believe I've figured this out, so I'm posting a second answer to preserve the prior discussion.

Here's the fix.  Remove this line:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

In my test script, this caused jQuery to send the `Content-Type` header `application/json; charset=utf-8`, as expected, but the actual contents of the request were not properly sent as JSON.  For example, rather than sending `{"foo":"bar"}`, it was sending `foo=bar`.  As a result, the receiving script acted as if no data was posted at all.  When I commented out the line above, my test script worked fine and did whatever I expected with the values received from the target URL.

Note that this will post your data as normal post data.  For example, if your `$.ajax()` call looks like this, the posted data will contain a variable named `foo` and one named `who`:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {foo : "bar",
        who : "what"},
    ...
});
```

If you want to post already-serialized JSON, do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: { somevariablename: '{"foo":"bar","who":"what"}' },
    ...
});
```

Then, you just have to parse the POST parameter `somevariablename` on the server side.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If its VS2012, try for adding Mime Type Handler, since VS2012 has IIS express and it need to add Mime type handler externally,
Add below code to web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

.. and if its not VS2012 then follow this link

[add .json handler support in IIS 7](http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/#.Uo2z3cRHJqX)